# What is the best way to profile/optimize google app engine application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Currently I am working on new App Engine application.

Unfortunately it seems that my application uses to lot of resources even for relatively small user number. So I need to determine its bottle necks and optimize them.

Answer (score 8):

[Appstats: RPC Instrumentation for Google App Engine](https://sites.google.com/site/appengineappstats/). It is being developed by Guido himself.

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/526/timelinea.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/526/timelinea.png)

**EDIT**: I believe AppStats will not work with Java, but there are some [tips here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/msg/bd51386e8719739e).

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Java, but looks very helpful

Comment: This is awesome. I've been using hooks to hack some timings together manually, glad I came across this :-)

Comment: As of release 1.3.2, it is now supported on Java.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse plugin for the Google App Engine provides a local App Engine environment in which you can run your program in debug or profile mode.  Perhaps this could provide the information you need?

Comment: Unfortunately for me, all API call performance perform very differently in local and production environments, also there is another very metrics which is very important for me - cost of request, data store operation or just simple method call (in USD ideally),  as well as how much this operation affects on my quota limits.