# Profiling a java Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans, profiling

Anyone know how to profile a Google App Engine for java app?  Preferably I'd like to use the build in netbeans profiler, but that has an error on startup when I try to use it.

Here is the error when I try to profile with netbeans 6.8:

```
runserver-profile:
     [java] Error occurred during initialization of VM
     [java] Could not find agent library in absolute path: C:\Program
```

Anyone know how to get the netbeans profiler working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to profile/optimize google app engine application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995401/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-optimize-google-app-engine-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [appwrench](http://appwrench.onpositive.com/). It was recomended in this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995401/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-optimize-google-app-engine-application/1995525#1995525).

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, currently it looks like its just for eclipse though