# Google App Engine Profiler

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, profiling, jprofiler

Is there any good profiler which support Google App Engine? I need to capture each methods call and their object creation. I have checked JProfiler, but it not supported methods level profiling.

Thanks

Comment: You can profile all the API calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995401/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-optimize-google-app-engine-application

Comment: Think you very much, It's working fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to profile in Google App Engine is using the `AppstatsServlet`. 
Add the following to your `web.xml`

```xml
<!-- AppStats start -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- AppStats end -->
```

and after perusing the pages that you want to profile, hit `http://yourappname.appspot.com/appstats/stats` with your browser. However it's profiling the API, but might be useful to you. In general object creation is orders of magnitude faster than API calls...

[Google documentation for Java AppStat](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is may not be the real profiling tool as what you think of.
But probably what you are looking for is [JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/)